# Want Popup menu in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, popup

-(IBAction)popup:(id)sender
   {

```
NomadPopupViewController *detailViewController = [[NomadPopupViewController alloc] init];
[self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
//[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
```

}

Getting this view , i want a popup menu inside this view controller when i click the leftnavigationbarbutton

[image]

Want this view .... 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try presentViewController, i try in one of my app

1)place this in viewDidLoad()

```
  self.modalPresentationStyle = 
   UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

2)this in click event

```
Popup *v2 = [[Popup   alloc]initWithNibName:@"Popup" bundle:nil];

v2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:v2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

3)Make your popup with UIViewController as u want to display

done enjoy!

Comment: Sorry for noob questions , But i am new to development . Can you tell me what is Nibname file . I am using storyboard . have not seen anything .

Comment: NibName refer to xib name of viewController, as i take custom xib for all viewController, sorry dude no more help from my side bcoz i never use storyboard for app development..good luck